# Javascript Dropdown Action

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to show divs based on input from a dropdown menu.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function display_div(show){
   document.getElementById(show).style.display = "";
}
</script>

<select name="passengers" id="passengers">
      <option selected="selected"> </option>
      <option onclick="display_div('passenger1');">1</option>
      <option onclick="display_div('passenger2');">2</option>
      <option onclick="display_div('passenger3');">3</option>
</select>
```

Nothing happens when I select an option. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is happening now? Error? Nothing? Do you have divs with ids=`passenger1`,...? I'm also pretty sure you don't want to use a hash as an ID or name (for your `select`)

Comment: .onchange try to alert something. first confirm  on change event is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after thinking back to some old problems i had, i remembered a problem that IE and Chrome have with the onClick event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function display_div(show){
   document.getElementById('passenger1').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('passenger2').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('passenger3').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById(show).style.display = "block";

}

</script>

<select id="optionList" onchange="display_div(document.getElementById('optionList').value);">
  <option selected="selected"> </option>
  <option value="passenger1">1</option>
  <option value="passenger2">2</option>
  <option value="passenger3">3</option>
</select>

<div id="passenger1" style="display:none;"> hey, 1 works </div>
<div id="passenger2" style="display:none;"> hey, 2 works </div>
<div id="passenger3" style="display:none;"> hey, 3 works </div>
```

The solution was to make the function call on the select and use onchange. Then it gets the selected options value and gives it to the function to work its magic

Comment: Unfortunately closing the function did not solve the problem.

Comment: Ok, ill have a go and get back to you in a few minutes

Comment: What's weird is that this works in Firefox but not Chrome... Any ideas?

Comment: well ill try chrome now and make fixes accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function display_div(show){
              document.getElementById('passenger1').style.display = "none";
              document.getElementById('passenger2').style.display = "none";
              document.getElementById('passenger3').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById(show).style.display = "block";
    }
   </script>

<select name="#" id="#">
      <option selected="selected"> </option>
      <option onclick="display_div('passenger1');">1</option>
      <option onclick="display_div('passenger2');">2</option>
      <option onclick="display_div('passenger3');">3</option>
</select>
```

You should use onchange if you want div shown upon changing.
Also you haven't set style property to block to show them. And to hide div use style.display = "none". Above code will work, but if you try to use if-else sequences you can minimize one transition from above code

Comment: I modified the code using your example. Still, nothing happens when an option is selected. The divs are in the following format: `<div id="passenger1" style="display:none;">
hey, 1 works
</div>`

Comment: @Mike My bad onchange is supposed to used with select element not with option change onchange with onclick it will work. i have tried on my computer and it is working. Ihave changed the function use it